# what is alternative function instead of setPreferredSize function in codenameone

Tags: java, codenameone

everyone
I found out earlier that setPreferredSize function is deprecated.
what is alternative of this function?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setPreferredSize(java.awt.Dimension) Doesn't say it's deprecated on official documentation.

Comment: Codename One not Swing Hugo

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.codenameone.com/blog/same-size-back-swipe where we discuss this further.

Generally `setPreferredSize` no longer has a valid use case.

If you are writing your own component, override `calcPreferredSize`.

If you are trying to make a component share a size with another component use the new `sameWidth`/`Height` functionality. If you want to increase the size of the component use padding/layout to achieve your desired results.

The reason `setPreferredSize` is bad is that it hardcodes the size for a specific situation but if the device rotates or the virtual keyboard resizes the screen you won't get notified (`calcPreferredSize` will get invoked though).

If you can point at a valid use case let us know. FYI we aren't likely to remove it anytime soon, we just want to discourage its usage.